# How to use multiple versions of NLTK on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, nltk

Consider the following scenario:

For our RnD, we have two systems. We have installed Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 on both. One system uses NLTK2, and other one NLTK3. Both system belongs to same project(s).

As syntax for NLTK code is different for both version, we are planning to install both version of NLTK on both system. But, question is: how to use two different version of NLTK on same system.

We shall appreciate any solution (or suggestion). We shall appreciate, if anyone can suggestion some solution to this problem using only either of one version of python.

Thanks in advance..

**NOTE**: I have tried to simplify scenario. Actual setup is more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Virtual Environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) to have both NTLK2 and NTLK3 on the same system.
I'm particularly fond of [this tutorial](http://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/).

Comment: Thank for the comment. I was not aware about _Virtual Environments_ in Python. It seems helpful. This is good idea (particularly) in production unit. In RnD, (I think) creation of new environment and activating it makes things more complicated. I shall wait for few more answers. If there is no better answer, then I shall _accept_ your answer.